# FOSUserBundle admin area not accessible after login

Tags: symfony, authentication, admin, fosuserbundle

I am using FOSUserBundle for admin section as well as frontend by following the instructions given at:

```
https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/issues/849
```

For frontend everything is working fine but for admin section when i access my admin area `/admin` 
then i am redirected to login page `/admin/login` (that is correct). Once i provide admin username and password then as per the default target path of after login

```
default_target_path: /admin/
```

defined in security.yml it is redirecting to `/admin` (that is also correct) but i am getting 403 forbidden error

```
**Access Denied**
403 Forbidden - AccessDeniedHttpException
1 linked Exception:
    AccessDeniedException
```

In my security.yml when i remove the below line:

```
- { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

then i am able to access /admin area after login.

I also observed that every time when i create a new user using `/register` at front end it is entering `a:0:{}` in the **roles** field of **fos_user** database table. Now i want to know :

What changes i will need to make at script level to create different types of users like admin, normal user etc. so that the above code of security.yml that i removed should work without removing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, created user has role `ROLE_USER` which is saved in DB like empty array converted to JSON `a:0:{}`. In FOSUserBundle exists some helpful [Command Line Tools](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/command_line_tools.md#fosuserbundle-command-line-tools). You should use *Promote a User* for set user `ROLE_ADMIN` like this:

```
$ php app/console fos:user:promote username ROLE_ADMIN
```

After that your `username` user will have access to admin panel where you can promote other users manually.

To create users with diferent `ROLE` types you should write event listener for `fos_user.registration.initialize` (or even `fos_user.registration.success`) event, like this:

```
class RegistrationListener
{
    public function setUserRole(UserEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        if (/* some conditions */) {
            $user = $event->getUser();
            $user->addRole('ROLE_STH');
        }
    }
}
```

Please be careful with using this listener for setting `ROLE_ADMIN`. *Promote a User* command is intended to add role like `ROLE_ADMIN`.

Comment: promoting a user to ROLE_ADMIN is working now but the issue is that admin user is also able to login at front-end that i dont want... What line of code i need to put in security.yml to restrict admin user to login at front end?

Comment: OK, so you can create separate `firewalls` for frontend and admin section. And User which is logged via one of firewall hasn't access to second one (by default, except `context` configuration). From other hand you can also write event listener for `fos_user.security.implicit_login` event and redirect user to specific part of your app.

Comment: Ok, i added - { path: ^/, role: ROLE_USER } in security.yml but still admin is able to login at fron end. I dont want to write any code using listener... is not it possible through security.yml? if yes then what would be the code?

Comment: In default SF2 role hierarhy `ROLE_ADMIN` has `ROLE_USER` too  (http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#hierarchical-roles). What wrong is with event listeners?

Comment: Actually i think if it could be managed from security.yml then it will save my time to write code for listener....Anyways thanks for all your response..... cheers !!

Answer (score 2):

@neeraj, as an answer to your comment here [FOSUserBundle admin area not accessible after login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18779655/fosuserbundle-admin-area-not-accessible-after-login/18779851#comment27689463_18779851)
as i know it's not possible to do it only with security.yml, but you can go with listener, not much to do.

create folder EventListener in your Bundle, then create SecurityListener.php

```
<?php

namespace Your\NameBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\InteractiveLoginEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;

class SecurityListener
{
    protected $router;
    protected $security;
    protected $dispatcher;

    public function __construct(Router $router, SecurityContext $security, EventDispatcher $dispatcher)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->security = $security;
        $this->dispatcher = $dispatcher;
    }

    public function onSecurityInteractiveLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event)
    {
        $this->dispatcher->addListener(KernelEvents::RESPONSE, array($this, 'onKernelResponse'));
    }

    public function onKernelResponse(FilterResponseEvent $event)
    {
        if ($this->security->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
            $response = new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('YOURCoreBundle_adminpage'));
        } elseif ($this->security->isGranted('ROLE_USER')) {
            $response = new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('YOURBundle_userpage'));
        } else {
            $response = new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('YOURCoreBundle_homepage'));
        }

        $event->setResponse($response);
    }
}
```

and in services.xml add

```
<parameters>
    <parameter key="yourbundle.listener.login.class">Your\NameBundle\EventListener\SecurityListener</parameter>
</parameters>

<services>
    <service id="yourbundle.listener.login" class="%yourbundle.listener.login.class%">
        <tag name="kernel.event_listener" event="security.interactive_login" method="onSecurityInteractiveLogin"/>
        <argument type="service" id="router"/>
        <argument type="service" id="security.context"/>
        <argument type="service" id="event_dispatcher"/>
    </service>
</services>
```