# In FOSUserBundle, How to initially set user role on REGISTRATION_COMPLETED event?

Tags: php, events, symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm trying to give each successfully registered user a `ROLE_USER` role. I'm new to FOSUserBundle, So from what I've read in the documentation, It's done by hocking logic into the controllers.

Here's my `NewUserGroupSet` Event listener:

```
<?php
namespace Tsk\TstBundle\EventListener;

use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\DocumentManager;
use FOS\UserBundle\Doctrine\UserManager;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FilterUserResponseEvent;
use FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

class NewUserGroupSet implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    protected $um;
    protected $dm;
    public function __construct(UserManager $um, DocumentManager $dm)
    {
        $this->um = $um;
        $this->dm = $dm;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETED => "onRegistrationSuccess",
        );
    }

    public function onRegistrationSuccess(FilterUserResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $user = $event->getUser();
        $user->setRoles(array('ROLE_USER'));
        $this->um->updateUser($user);
        $this->dm->flush();
    }
}
?>
```

And is registered as a service as follows:

```
parameters:
    tsk_user.group_set.class: Tsk\TstBundle\EventListener\NewUserGroupSet

services:
    tsk_user.group_set:
        class: %tsk_user.group_set.class%
        arguments: [@fos_user.user_manager, @doctrine.odm.mongodb.document_manager]
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```

But when I register a new user, Nothing happens. No roles is being set whatsoever.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried calling  `addRole()` FOSUser entity function,if you notice the setRole function in entity it is looping through the array to roles and passing it to `addRole`

```
public function setRoles(array $roles)
{
    $this->roles = array();

    foreach ($roles as $role) {
        $this->addRole($role);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Try with `addRole()` for single role

```
public function onRegistrationSuccess(FilterUserResponseEvent $event)
{
    $user = $event->getUser();
    $user->addRole('ROLE_USER');
    $this->um->updateUser($user);
    $this->dm->flush();
}
```

Comment: @RafaelAdel read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18779655/fosuserbundle-admin-area-not-accessible-after-login) carefully it states that *By default, created user has role ROLE_USER which is saved in DB like empty array converted to JSON a:0:{}* try to `var_dump($this->getRoles())` after creation of user

Comment: Ah, I got it. I tried to add `ROLE_ADMIN` role and it worked. Thanks a lot for your effort.