# Fosuser bundle - setting role to user

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I want to set role for user. I ąm using code below:

```
    $user = this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('BlogBundle:User')->findOneById('11');
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $t=array('ROLE_ADMIN');
    $user->setRoles($t);
    $em->persist($user);
    $em->flush();
    return new Response('okk');
```

When I set 'ROLE_ADMIN' everything is ok, but when I set 'ROLE_USER' database cell is empty. Why?

Thank you for help in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18779655/fosuserbundle-admin-area-not-accessible-after-login

By default, created user has role ROLE_USER which is saved in DB like empty array converted to JSON a:0:{}

Is the value of the column an empty value or the representation of an empty json array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The roles column in your users table, should have

```
a:0:{}
```

for users with just the role `ROLE_USER`

Programmatic way of checking .

check if a user has a particular role ( inclusing ROLE_USER )

```
if ($this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_USER')) {
    // the user has the ROLE_USER role
}
```

there's also

```
$user->getRoles()
```

One more way to double check if the use really has the `ROLE_USER`

```
php app/console fos:user:promote
```

When prompted, enter the username followed by `ROLE_USER`

it should state that

> User "example@example.com" did already have "ROLE_USER" role.

Answer (score 0):

In FOS User Bundle, all users have the `ROLE_USER` role. It would be redundant to add/save this role.

If you're looking for it in FOSUserBundle's code base, the role is aliased as `ROLE_DEFAULT` in the `UserInterface` class.

Comment: Thanks all for answers